# Need a license to sell computer made from OEM components and windows OEM?

Tags: windows-7, license, oem

As the title says do I need a license to sell a computer made using OEM components and that has windows 7 OEM included? Or if I don't need a license os there anything else I must do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As long as the Windows 7 OEM sticker is attached to that PC you are good to go.